# Is it possible to return transfered ArrayBuffer back original typed array?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I understand that transferring objects to a Web Worker causes the main thread to lose ownership. I am wondering if there is any way for it to regain ownership. This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bhx044Kj68rK76eMVHun?p=preview) (code below) demonstrates the issue I am having.

**main.js**

```
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
var z = new Int16Array(10);
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);  // [0, 1, ... 10]
    console.log(z);  // [], ownership not regained here
}
console.log(z);  // [0, 0, ... 0], original value here
worker.postMessage(z, [z.buffer]);
console.log(z);  // [], ownership lost here
```

**worker.js**

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    var data = e.data;  // transferred "z" from main.js
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data[i] = i;
    }
    // I thought this would return ownership back to the main thread
    self.postMessage(data, [data.buffer]);
}
```

Essentially, the end goal is to change the value of `z` in the main thread from within the worker thread, without having to copy the results in the main thread after the message is received. However, it seems that the ownership of `z` is retained by the worker. Am I misunderstanding something? Is there a way to accomplish this?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, can you do `z=e.data` in main js `onmessage` handler?

Comment: In reality I am working with WebGL buffers. Setting the variable isn't enough for WebGL, unfortunately. I would have to go and re-bind the buffers. I could probably make it work, but it's not ideal.

Comment: I guess this is more of a conceptual question. I would imagine transferring ownership can work both ways for a single entity, but I can't figure out how to return ownership back once it gets to the worker.

Comment: It seems to me that the effectiveness of an actor model using javascript threads hinges on this question.  Hope someone has an answer.  Looks like browsers / node does not properly respect that parameter coming from the worker threads though.

Comment: It is not possible. After losing ownership the `Int16Array` becomes invalid. Typed arrays are immutable, so it's invalid forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that. The `Int16Array` is just an interface wrapping over `ArrayBuffer`, which is where the real binary data are stored. When you transfer the ownership, the `Int16Array` is invalidated (set to 0 length). In your worker, new `Int16Array` is created and assigned to the old `ArrayBuffer`. I crated this image for you:

[image: image description]

1. Post message removes buffer from the typed array.
2. Everything that is not Transferable (that is `ArrayBuffer`) is serialized to [Structured clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), array buffer is transfered
3. The `Int16Array` object has no longer a buffer and therefore is invalid
4. Structured clone is deserialized and that creates new `Int16Array` instance, this instance receives transferred ArrayBuffer

Obviously, interpreter cannot have an idea that you returned the `ArrayBuffer` back, so the typed array remains invalid forever.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So the problem is that the `ArrayBuffer` cannot be re-associated with the `Int16Array` from 3. when the ownership is transferred back from the worker to the main thread?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, once you transfer the buffer the original typed array object is useless. You have to creat a new one. Unless you transfer megabytes od data, just use a copy if you need to maintain the data in the origimal instance.